# Matplotlib with TkAgg error: PyEval_RestoreThread: null tstate on save_fig() - do I need threads enabled?

Tags: python, c, matplotlib

I'm puzzling over an embedded *Python 2.7.2 interpreter* issue.  I've embedded the interpreter in a *Visual C++ 2010* application and it essentially just calls user-written scripts.

My end-users want to use `matplotlib` - I've already resolved a number of issues relating to its dependence on numpy - but when they call `savefig()`, the application crashes with:

`**Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate`

This isn't an issue running the same script using the standard *Python 2.7.2 interpreter*, even using the same site-packages, so it seems to definitely be something wrong with my embedding.  I call `Py_Initialize()` - do I need to do something with setting up Python threads?

I can't quite get the solution from other questions here to work, but I'm more concerned that this is symptomatic of a wider problem in how I'm setting up the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved this - so going to explain what occurred for the sake of Googlers!

This only happened when using third-party libraries like numpy or matplotlib, but actually related to an error elsewhere in my code.  As part of the software I wrote, I was extending the Python interpreter following the same basic pattern as shown in the Python C API documentation.

At the end of this code, I called the Py_DECREF function on some of the Python objects I had created along the way.  My mistake was that I was calling this function on *borrowed* references, which should not be done.

This caused the software to crash with the error above when it reached the Py_Finalize command that I used to clean up.  Removing the DECREF on the borrowed references fixed this error.